# Evaluating an Infinite Limit that Wolfram doesn't like!

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}  \ln (n +1) n(n+1)^{-n/(n+1)}- \ln (n)n^{1/n}. $$

According to Wolfram, this is equivalent to $0$, yet everything I've tried (like log-exponent) doesn't lead me to the answer. Could someone show why this is true? And why doesn't Wolfram have a step-by-step for this?

Comment: Could you provide the Wolfram Alpha link?  What do you get for $n=100$?

Comment: Here is the wolfram link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n-%3E+infinity+ln%28n%2B1%29+n%28n%2B1%29%5E%28-n%2F%28n%2B1%29%29+%2B+ln%28n%29+%28-n%5E%281%2Fn%29%29

for $n = 100$ you have that it's a very small negative number: $-0.039138$... I don't see what the problem is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asymptotically expand the individual terms:

$$\underbrace{\ln (n +1)}_{\sim \log(n) + \frac{1}{n} + \mathcal O(\frac{1}{n^2})}  \underbrace{n(n+1)^{-n/(n+1)}}_{\sim 1+\frac{\log(n)-1}{n} + \mathcal O(\frac{1}{n^2})} - \ln (n)\underbrace{n^{1/n}}_{\sim 1 + \frac{\log(n)}{n} + \mathcal O(\frac{1}{n^2})}$$

Then in total you get

$$\begin{aligned}
&\sim \left(\log(n) + \tfrac{1}{n} + \mathcal O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})\right)\left(1+\tfrac{\log(n)-1}{n} + \mathcal O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})\right) - \log(n)\left(1 + \tfrac{\log(n)}{n} + \mathcal O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})\right)
\\&\sim  \log(n) + \tfrac{\log(n)^2-\log(n)}{n} + \frac{1}{n}+\tfrac{\log(n)-1}{n^2}   + -\log(n) -\tfrac{\log(n)^2}{n} + \mathcal O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})
\\&\sim -\tfrac{\log(n)-1}{n} + \tfrac{\log(n)-1}{n^2} + \mathcal O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Nice and elegant!